# WordPress Taxonomy MySQL Query - OUTER JOIN not returning any rows

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I'm probably missing something obvious here. I've got a WordPress taxonomy which has regions (a county) and subregions (a neighborhood) through the `parent` column of `wp_term_taxonomy`. I'm trying to write a query which will return a row regardless of whether a subregion exists (still returning the county). In this example, I'm querying for a region I know exists in the database ('PHILADELPHIA') with a subregion I know does not exist ('asdfasdfasdf'). If I change 'asdfasdfasdf' to a subregion I know exists, the row returns fine, but I'm not getting NULLs in the RIGHT table if the subregion doesn't exist as I expect to (no rows returns, as if it were doing an INNER JOIN). Here's the query:

```
SELECT region_wtt.term_taxonomy_id AS region_ttid,
    region_wtt.term_id AS region_tid,
    region_wt.name AS region_name,
    subregion_wtt.term_taxonomy_id AS subregion_ttid,
    subregion_wtt.term_id AS subregion_tid,
    subregion_wt.name AS subregion_name

FROM wp_term_taxonomy region_wtt

RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy subregion_wtt
ON region_wtt.term_taxonomy_id = subregion_wtt.parent

RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_terms region_wt
ON region_wtt.term_id = region_wt.term_id

RIGHT OUTER JOIN wp_terms subregion_wt
ON subregion_wtt.term_id = subregion_wt.term_id

WHERE region_wtt.taxonomy='tsml_region'
    AND region_wtt.parent = 0
    AND region_wt.name='PHILADELPHIA'
    AND subregion_wtt.taxonomy='tsml_region'
    AND subregion_wt.name='asdfasdfasdf';
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The RIGHT OUTER JOIN will not return results if none are found. You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to return NULL when no results exist. You may need to use a combination of the two to achieve what you need.

Comment: I haven't used MySQL in ages, I really wish it has FULL JOIN support. A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in this case also doesn't turn any rows.

Comment: If you supply some sample data I think you'll find that someone will answer this pretty quickly for you.